# How to pass constructor dependency in Laravel service provider

Tags: laravel-5

I am registering my Social authentication service in service provider, the implementation of my interface requires parameters in its constructor function.

How to pass it via service provider? Here is my code but it's syntactically incorrect.

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use App;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory as Socialite;

class SocialAuthenticationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        App::bind('App\Repositories\SocialAuthenticationInterface', function () {
            return new App\Repositories\SocialAuthentication(Socialite $socialite, Guard $auth, User $user);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to use the new keyword instead of assigning your dependecies to a variable. And make sure your classes are imported (eg. use Guard) at the top of the class.

```
public function register()
{
    App::bind('App\Repositories\SocialAuthenticationInterface', function () {
        return new App\Repositories\SocialAuthentication(new Socialite, new Guard, new User);
    });
}
```

Comment: it returns a fatal error, "Cannot instantiate interface Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory".